# Dispay data from database to textbox asp.net mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, textbox

How will I properly display data from database to textbox when the button "search" is clicked? It should display the item name and the price of that product code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/StKht.png)

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
{
    using(MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities())
    {
        var products = from s in db.Products
                       select s;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            products = products.Where(s => s.ProductCode.Equals(searchString));
        }
        return View(products.ToList());
    }
}
```

Index

```
<div class="form-group">
    <table style="text-align:left; margin-bottom:10px;">
        <tr>
            <td>Item Code</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        </td>
        <tr style="background-color:lightgray;">
            <td colspan="2"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-info"id="buttonsearch" value="Search" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>  
        @foreach (var item in Model) { 
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left;">Item Name</td
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=> item.ProductName)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unit Price</td>
                <td style="text-align:right;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)</td>
            </tr>
        }
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">Quantity</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="quantity" class="input-sm" />
                <span class="error">Product Name  required</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:left;">Discount</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="discount" class="input-sm" style="text-align:right;" placeholder="0.00" />
                <span class="error">Product Name required</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: so, where is your problem?

Comment: when I clicked the search button, all data  including those product that has different product code has been displayed in the textbox

Comment: You can use ajax to post your 'searchString' and return a partial view of the products and then update the DOM with the view that was returned (or you could just put the `@Html.TextBox("SearchString")` inside a form with `FormMethod.Get` but that would mean reloading the page each time.

Comment: But you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate controls for you collection (refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) but its not clear what your doing with that since you have not shown any form tags in your view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of .ToList() use .FirstOrDefault(); just in case you want to populate one record in your textbox.

Comment: shows an error message The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'Final_SPARK_OSIMS.Product', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Final_SPARK_OSIMS.Product]'.

Comment: @Pearl try adding this piece in your View:

'@model IEnumerable<YourProjectName.Models.Product>'
Hope this helps.